# Create a branch from another branch without tracking it

Tags: git, git-checkout

Usually, I create a branch like this:

```
git checkout branch
git checkout -b new_branch
```

It works well because it doesn't automatically set an upstream branch so it shows me the warning to push to setup the upstream. I usually copy paste it and then it tracks correctly a remote branch...

That said it's pretty cumbersome...

So I started using a new method to reduce the amount of steps:

```
git checkout -b new_branch from_branch
```

Unfortunately it gives me this output:

```
git checkout -b xxx origin/staging
Branch xxx set up to track remote branch staging from origin.
...
```

So when I try to push, it gives me this error:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match
```

Obviously the upstream isn't the one I wanted... I'd rather have it automatically add origin/xxx or no upstream at all.

I see there is a "`--no-track`" option; is there a way to make it the default? I haven't got success using the track option.

Comment: If you have a local branch that is already tracking `origin/staging`, and branch from that, you shouldn't get the warning (I think).

Comment: `git push origin -u xxx:xxx`.

Comment: @Andy there is a branch already tracking staging and I don't want to track staging I want to track the new branch that I created which doesn't exist yet remotely on origin like I'd do with --set-upstream for the first push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr: you probably want to do `git config --global push.default=upstream`, but there are other settings for the exact operation a bare `git push` will perform that might be more congenial to your workflow.

---

Git's defaults have been an ongoing work.  The operation a bare `git push` performed was once ... well, the C++ term for it is "expert friendly", it makes perfect sense to people who understand, but is a surprise to people still finding their legs.  So then git added a `push.default` setting, and various "modes", ways of deciding what a bare `git push` would do, with the idea of finding and eventually switching to something reasonable that wouldn't lead newbies to complaining about the damage they'd just unwittingly done.

The short form is, the new factory-default behavior is effectively a child-proof cap, something you just have to learn to get past, and it stops the unwary from hurting themselves.

If you read [the `git push` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_description) it alludes to all this and points you to the `git config` docs for `push.default`:

> When the command line does not specify what to push with `<refspec> ...` arguments or `--all`, `--mirror`, `--tags` options, the command finds the default `<refspec>` by consulting `remote.*.push` configuration, and if it is not found, honors `push.default` configuration to decide what to push (See [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault) for the meaning of `push.default`).
>
> **When neither the command-line nor the configuration specify what to push, the default behavior is used, which corresponds to the `simple` value for `push.default`: the current branch is pushed to the corresponding upstream branch, but as a safety measure, the push is aborted if the upstream branch does not have the same name as the local one**.

and [the other options are](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-pushdefault)

> #### push.default
>
> Defines the action git push should take if no refspec is explicitly given. Different values are well-suited for specific workflows; for instance, in a purely central workflow (i.e. the fetch source is equal to the push destination), upstream is probably what you want. Possible values are:
>
> - nothing - do not push anything (error out) unless a refspec is explicitly given. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
> - current - push the current branch to update a branch with the same name on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
> - upstream - push the current branch back to the branch whose changes are usually integrated into the current branch (which is called @{upstream}). This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. central workflow).
> - simple - in centralized workflow, work like upstream with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one.
>
>   When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as current. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners.
>
>   This mode has become the default in Git 2.0.
> - matching - push all branches having the same name on both ends. This makes the repository you are pushing to remember the set of branches that will be pushed out (e.g. if you always push maint and master there and no other branches, the repository you push to will have these two branches, and your local maint and master will be pushed there).
>
>   To use this mode effectively, you have to make sure all the branches you would push out are ready to be pushed out before running git push, as the whole point of this mode is to allow you to push all of the branches in one go. If you usually finish work on only one branch and push out the result, while other branches are unfinished, this mode is not for you. Also this mode is not suitable for pushing into a shared central repository, as other people may add new branches there, or update the tip of existing branches outside your control.
>
>   This used to be the default, but not since Git 2.0 (simple is the new default).

Comment: I'll have to play with that. I believe current is what I want, as I said, using "git checkout -b new_branch origin/staging" will set upstream to origin/staging so I believe that if I use the upstream mode, it will push to origin/staging which is not what I want. current is more like it. In practice, I never had issues with the old behaviour.  At least, it's easy to keep all branches in sync without forgetting to push something.

Answer (score 14):

As you noted, the `git checkout` command supports the same `--track` / `--no-track` options as `git branch`, so to make a new branch `zorblatt` point to the same *commit* as `origin/master`, yet not have `origin/master` as its (wrong) upstream:

```
git checkout -b zorblatt --no-track origin/master
```

Unfortunately, there's no way to default to that. (Curiously, there *is* a configuration knob for [git-gui](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gui.html), `gui.matchTrackingBranch`.)

(Aside: the old verb, track, kind of sucks: "branch X tracks remote-tracking branch Y/Z" and pretty soon the words "branch" and "track" no longer seem to mean *anything*. "Have as upstream" is clumsy, but at least it is not from the Department of Redundancy Department.)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, there is no default configuration for this, however a way to do this without `--no-track` is to use the [`^{}` revision suffix](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html):

```
git checkout -b new_branch origin/master^{}
```

The suffix tells git to refer to the object behind the branch, rather than the branch itself.

I like this approach because the intent is more explicit, which is especially important when it comes to certain tagging scenarios. For example, using `git tag -a TagB TagA` would actually have `TagB` referring to `TagA` itself, rather than the commit underlying it. To avoid nesting tags, you can use `git tag -a TagB TagA^{}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `--no-track` flag is going to be your friend here. It will accomplish your ultimate goal of not tracking a remote branch when you create a new branch using the checkout command instead of the branch command.

This only saves you three keystrokes though, so it is still a lot to type. You can wrap this up in a git alias to simplify things, here is the one I use for this task:

```
git config --global alias.nb '!bash -c "git checkout -b $1 --no-track ${2-origin/master}" -'
```

This accepts 2 parameters and calls out to bash to complete the action. We use branch-per-feature and (almost) always start new branches from master so I made second parameter optional and use origin/master as the default.

To use HEAD as the default, just change `${2-origin/master}` to `$2`, or substitute your own branch name to fit your team's workflow.

Usage:

```
git nb <branch-name> [<source-commit>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `git config --global branch.autoSetupMerge simple` before creating a new branch.

> `branch.autoSetupMerge`
>
> Tells git branch, git switch, and git checkout to set up new branches so that git pull will appropriately merge from the starting point branch.
>
> `simple` — automatic setup is done only when the starting point is a remote-tracking branch and the new branch has the same name as the remote branch.

This way, when doing `git switch -c bar origin/foo`, `bar` won't be set up to track `origin/foo`, since the branch names aren't the same.

Ref: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchautoSetupMerge

Answer (score -1):

> it works well because it doesn't automatically set an upstream branch

You are right and wrong on the same time. How is it possible?
Well it depends on you git version.
Git version 1.X will work in a different way that git v2.X.

you upstream depend on the git version that you used to create your branch. If you used 1.X and created a branch and than updated your git version and created a new branch both of them will behave different.

You can always edit manually the `.git/config` file to see your tracking branches. `git remote -v` will print them to your screen.

### `git release notes 2.0`

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/Documentation/RelNotes/2.0.0.txt

> When `git push [$there]` does not say what to push, we have used the
>   traditional **`matching`** semantics so far **(all your branches were sent
>   to the remote as long as there already are branches of the same name
>   over there)**.
>
> In Git 2.0, the default is now the **`simple`** semantics,

---

## What can you do instead?

As you discovered the `--no-track` option will create a branch without upstream.

#### Another option :

You can create an orphan branch (branch with no history) and than use cherry-pick to add all the desired history to it.

```
git checkout --orphan <new_branch> [<sha-1>]
```

Now you will empty history and you can add any commit you desired to it.

Comment: It's not really answering the question. The orphan part is simply off topic. What I really want is branch from an other branch and make the new branch track the new branch remotely instead of the branch I branched from... At the same time... checking it out.